# Test multiple axios calls inside react component using jest and testing-library

Tags: axios, jestjs, react-testing-library, avalara

There are multiple axios call in my react component. I am trying to test responses wrt URL. But how to check on URL's.

Below is the code:

```
import mockAxios from "jest-mock-axios";
// other test cases inside describe
mockAxios.get.mockImplementation((url) => {
  console.log("url", url);
  switch (url) {
    case "//companies/123/activity":
      return Promise.resolve({ data: [] });
    case "//activity/events":
      return Promise.resolve({ data: [] });
    case "//companies/123/activity/users":
      return Promise.resolve({ data: [] });
    default:
      return Promise.reject(new Error("not found"));
  }
});
```

But not getting url, the arg is empty.

Comment: Show the code under test

Comment: The changes worked on closing and reopening VS. Thanks guys for your help and time!